# How to use @Scheduled annotation in Non-Spring Boot Projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a project in Spring without Spring Boot
and I'm not using xml configurations, instead I'm using annotations.
Then how to use `@Schedule(cron="bla bla...")`
where should I put `@EnableScheduling`.
Below is my piece of code which is not working:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 40 22 * * SUN")
    public void routinessundayBAS1() throws EntityNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("coming");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jakub said, you have to add `@EnableScheduling` on any `@Configuration` class. You could configure the scheduler to customize your configuration by implementing the `SchedulingConfigurer` interface. An example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("PACKAGES WITH SCHEDULED ANNOTATIONS")
public class ConfigScheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    ...    
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {

       ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
       scheduler.setPoolSize( threadpoolsize );
       scheduler.setThreadGroupName( threadgroupname );
       scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix( threadPrefix );
       scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds( timeout );    
       return scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar registrar) {      
        TaskScheduler scheduler = this.taskScheduler();
        registrar.setTaskScheduler( scheduler );
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `@EnableScheduling` on any `@Configuration` class.